# JQgrid validation with JQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jqgrid

I'm doing a project which use JQgrid. Currently I'm doing the validation of the add and the edit of the navgrid with the following strategy:

```
.navGrid('#pager',{edit:true,add:true,del:true},
            {//EDITAR
                jqModal:false,
                reloadAfterSubmit:true,
                savekey: [true,13],
                drag: true,
                closeOnEscape:true,
                closeAfterAdd:true,
                closeAfterEdit:true,
                url:"http://localhost/ProyectoNetbeans/CodeIgniter_2.1.3/index.php/Profesiones_controller/editData",

                beforeSubmit: function(postdata, formid){//valida que no halla errores en la insercion de datos
                    if (postdata.descripcion=="")
                    {
                        return [false,'error message 1'];
                    }
                    else if (postdata.descripcion.length>200)
                    {
                        return [false,'error message 2'];
                    }
                    else if ((revisarSiRepetido(postdata.descripcion))==true)
                    {
                         return [false,'error message 3'];
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        return [true,'EXITO']; // no error
                    }

                }

            },
```

Here I am validating the form data in the beforeSubmit function . I was wondering if it is possible to use the JQuery validation plugin to do this validations, or if there is another method that is better than this one, because in this way I have to do a lot of validation when the grids are bigger, and the code is more error prone, so if somone can do a recomendation for this it will be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You really need to be using a `form` to take advantage of the jQuery validation plugin. I'm sure you can find other validation tools but then the question is if it's worth the overhead vs using the jqGrid validation.

Comment: Thanks for answering Mark. I just wanted to be sure if there is some other method to achieve this, but its true, if I'm going to spend a lot of time implementing that validation, it will not be worth the effort. If somebody knows an alternate and better method, please post the answer.

Comment: Glad I could help, Please mark as correct if you don't get a more "correct" answer.